# Unix - Dependent tasks execution

Tags: linux, shell, unix, dependencies

I have four tasks to execute in the unix, but each task is dependent upon the completion of the previous task.

The task cannot be executed until the previous task is finished

```
nohup ./aa_batch_initial.ksh -s 10011 $UP
nohup ./aa_batch_initial.ksh -s 10021 $UP
```

How can I write it in shell scripting?

Answer (score 1):

In bash `&&` can be used to concate commands. So the following should serve your purpose.

```
task1 && task2 && task3 && task4
```

Answer (score 0):

Commands are executed in sequential order in a shell. That means you can simply place your commands ("tasks") one after another and they will be executed in that order, one after another. So the next command is always started after the previous command has finished.

Here is a simple bash example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `date +"%H:%M:%S"` >> test.out;
sleep 5;
echo `date +"%H:%M:%S"` >> test.out;
sleep 5;
echo `date +"%H:%M:%S"` >> test.out;
sleep 5;
echo `date +"%H:%M:%S"` >> test.out;
```

The output of that script in file `test.out` is:

```
11:24:47
11:24:52
11:24:57
11:25:02
```

The `nohup` utility only comes into play if you want to detach from the script, for example if you want to execute something on a remote system but not keep an interactive session open. In that case you apply the `nohup` command to the script execution, not to the single commands inside that script.

An alternative to that would be the `screen` utility which gives you more freedom, it basically keeps a shell session open even after you disconnect and allows you to reconnect to that running session at a later point in time.